Why has my USB flash drive's mounted name suddenly changed?
For a couple of years, my USB flash drive has mounted at "/media/$USER/1234-5678" where 1234-5678 is the device UUID. I have a backup script written which uses this mount point to run.
Last week, my backup failed because the mount point could not be found. (As a note, though I first noticed this problem last week, I had not backed up my flash drive in about a month, so that's the range during which whatever changed happened.) Looking into it, I see that now, for no reason I know of, my flash drive is now mounting at "/media/$USER/USB DRIVE"
I don't really mind revising my backup script (and have, in fact, already done so), but I'm curious as to what changed, if anyone has any ideas.
I'm on 22.04.4 LTS with all updates applied.

Mount by-label and it will stay the samen unless you alter the label :)

I'll give that a try. Thanks!
